# How can I cover this LOG statement under catch block in Junit testing

Tags: java, authentication, exception, junit

How can I cover this LOG statement under catch block in Junit testing.

```
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CCRedirectInfo.class);

@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        try (ResourceResolver readerResourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(
                SERVICE_MAPPING)) {
            String originUrl = request.getParameter("origin");
            loggedinUrl = readerResourceResolver.map(originUrl);
        } catch (LoginException loginException) {
            LOG.error("Exception happened while fetching the ResourceResolver ", loginException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your aim to test if the logging is happening as expected when the exception happens? What are you using - Log4j?

Comment: what I'm told to do is you should trick the code such way so that it jumps out of try block to catch block and cover that in UT. package is  org.slf4j

Comment: OK. But it is still not clear if your question is "How to generate the condition?" or "I know how to generate the condition, but want to know how to test if the log happened."

Comment: actually I don't know how to generate that condition so that catch block gets executed